# Let me understand this recursive function of PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I am trying to understand this recursive function. When i echo out with different numbers it returns different result. I can't understand how this is working actually.

```
    <?php 
       function head_sum($x) {
        return ($x == 1) ? $x : $x + head_sum($x - 1);
    }


    echo head_sum(5);//15
    echo head_sum(2);//3
    echo head_sum(3);//6
```

Comment: `$x = 5` then `5 == 1` return false, `5+ head_sum(5-1)` ie. 5+ head_sum(4)..
 Answer: `5+ head_sum(4) + head_sum(3) + head_sum(2) + head_sum(1) = 15`

Comment: It calculates a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function right now says:

```
if variable x equals 1 then
return variable x
else
return variable x + this function( variable x -1 )
```

So this will keep running until $x equals 1. Until then it will keep adding itself.

```
So when you type echo head_sum(5):
head_sum(5); //$x = 5
head_sum(4); //$x = 5+4
head_sum(3); //$x = 5+4+3
head_sum(2); //$x = 5+4+3+2
head_sum(1); //$x = 5+4+3+2+1 = 15
```

---

This can also be represented like this (hope i can show this properly without whiteboard)

```
function headsum(5){
    return 5 + head_sum( 5-1 ){
        return 4 + head_sum( 4-1 ){
            return 3 + head_sum( 3-1 ){
                return 2 + head_sum( 2-1 ){
                    return 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope This makes some sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call head_sum it's called multiple times.
First pass-through goes all the way until the inner `head_sum` calls itself.
It continues to do so until it decreased by `1` down to `1` at which point the conditional exits out.

So for `head_sum(5)`

`5` goes in and `i` saved to `$x`.

Inside recursion calls

```
head_sum( 5 -1 ) // 4
```

Then `3`

Then `2`

Then `1`

The `( $x == 1 )` check exits the function after adding the total tally which at this point is incremented to:

```
5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15
```

Comment: Thanks for proper syntax. I'll be more precise. Good man!

Comment: thanks all of you. Now i can understand :)

Comment: @jimmy thats a great illustration! So easy to understand. thanks